# gnome-control-center in VirtualBox Ubuntu live-cd guest?

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, software-center, opengl

In Virtual Box 6.0.8 (on Ubuntu 18.04 host), I'm running an Ubuntu 18.04 live CD image as guest (so, not installed).

So, I tried to run `gnome-control-center`, because I want to try to disable mouse integration (as per [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1229281/39752); Guest Additions have been installed); but if I run:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gnome-control-center 
OpenGL Warning: Failed to connect to host. Make sure 3D acceleration is enabled for this VM.
```

[#9889 (OpenGL Warning: Failed to connect to host. Make sure 3D acceleration is enabled for this VM.) – Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9889):

> User that issues startx, should be part of group: vboxguest

OK:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo usermod -a -G vboxguest ubuntu
usermod: group 'vboxguest' does not exist

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo groupadd vboxguest 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo usermod -a -G vboxguest ubuntu
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gnome-control-center 

(gnome-control-center:10127): dbind-WARNING **: 20:37:38.574: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
OpenGL Warning: Failed to connect to host. Make sure 3D acceleration is enabled for this VM.
```

Right, but if I run as sudo, this warning appears:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gnome-control-center 
OpenGL Warning: crPixelCopy3D:  simply crMemcpy'ing from srcPtr to dstPtr
```

... and a window gets raised, however it's empty:

[image: vbox-gnomecc]

Any ideas how I could properly start `gnome-control-center` in this case (liveCD image as VirtualBox guest)?

Answer (score 0):

From what I found in: [#18239 (No Mouse visibility on VM -> fixed in releases after 6.0.4) – Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18239):

> In "VirtualBox > Settings > Display" for the guest, I changed the "Graphics Controller" to "VBoxSVGA" [...]
>
> VBoxSVGA is the wrong option, as it's used for Win guests. Are you sure you didn't change it to VMSVGA, which is the proper one for Linux guests?

I shut down the guest VM, changed the display to VMSVGA, booted guest again, and now `gnome-control-center` starts in full.